# How to make Offline database with online synchronization in android app using JAVA. Plesae suggest me code or any related tutorial

Tags: database, sqlite, synchronization, android-room

I have 8k data in my server. i want to use it into my android apps. i want to store volley response into my app for offline use. when phone data connection will off it will work and when data connection is available it will try to collect data from API response.

Please Explain and suggest Code or related tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Volley then it's automatically caches the response based on cache header...

please go through this example,

```
// Initialize Volley RequestQueue (usually in Application class)
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

// Make a network request (GET example)
String url = "https://api.example.com/data";
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
    response -> {
        // Handle the response (parse JSON, update UI, etc.)
        // Store the response in your local cache (SQLite, SharedPreferences, etc.)
    },
    error -> {
        // Handle error (retry, show error message, etc.)
    });

// Add the request to the queue
requestQueue.add(request);
```